# getline with filestream is capturing the lines in regex format

Tags: c++

I have a file with ~40k lines, and I want to capture certain words from it. The condition for the same is that the word should be enclosed in curly brackets, i.e. `{ }`.

Also, it is guaranteed that the left opening bracket will always be the first character in every line, and a valid pair always exists. For this, I wrote the following code:

```
fstream file("file_name.txt");
string line;
while(getline(file, line)) {
    string word;
    if(line[0] == '{'){
        int i = 1;

        while(line[i] != '}'){
            word.push_back(line[i]);
            i++;
        }

        if(line[i] == '}'){
            cout<<word<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The first two lines in my file are:

1. `Hello, this is the starting line of the file.`
2. `{This} is a word you are supposed to capture.`

However, after running, I do not get any output in the console. When I debugged the code, the `line` parameter appeared to be in the following regex format:

1. `"\xff\xfeH\0e\0l\0l\0o\0,\0 \0t\0h\0i\0s\0 \0i\0s\0 \0t\0h\0e\0 \0s\0t\0a\0r\0t\0i\0n\0g\0 \0l\0i\0n\0e\0 \0o\0f\0 \0t\0h\0e\0 \0f\0i\0l\0e\0.\0\r\0"`
2. `"\0{\0T\0h\0i\0s\0}\0 \0i\0s\0 \0a\0 \0w\0o\0r\0d\0 \0y\0o\0u\0 \0a\0r\0e\0 \0s\0u\0p\0p\0o\0s\0e\0d\0 \0t\0o\0 \0c\0a\0p\0t\0u\0r\0e\0.\0\r\0"`

How do I force `getline()` to capture the lines in plain text without any regex? Or how should I modify my code to account for this situation?

Comment: When I run this code on my own machine I get the expected output of `This`. Is it possible that your `file_name.txt` is actually in a binary format not text?

Comment: Is the input file properly encoded? This is working fine for me. Btw: You could use `std::string::find` to find the position of the closing bracket and `std::string::substr` to extract the substring in one go...

Comment: The two starting bytes, `fffe`, is a BOM (byte order mark). Nothing to do with regex.

Comment: Wrong encoding is a possibility indeed! How do I check the same and properly format it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did not know that, thanks for letting me know! Do you suggest any resources to read up more about it?

Comment: @AdityaPrakash I think the wiki page on [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, it was an issue with file encoding. I just re-encoded it to be `UTF-8` and it works perfectly now. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: What makes you think that a bunch of binary is a 'regex format'?

Comment: @user207421 regex is used synonymous here for illegible gibberish :)

Comment: @BitTickler Obviously, but that neither explains nor excuses it. I have asked the OP for an explanation. It is up to him to provide it.

Answer (score -1):

So the issue was that the file was not formatted properly. It was encoded in UTF-16, and upon changing it to UTF-8, the code worked without any issues.

Stealing Ted's comment:

> The two starting bytes, fffe, is a BOM ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). Nothing to do with regex.

I was wrong to assume that some gibberish would be regex :P I hope this helps someone.